# Batch: what is the pipe | used for?

Tags: batch-file, syntax, cmd, operators

Hello stackoverflow users!

I'm not really new to batch. I just never used pipes `|` in batch and even after I read reference on ss64.com I don't understand what's the pipe used for.

At first I thought it is OR operator or something (obviously I know now it's not).

I only know that it's located between two lines (commands) like `&`, but I still don't get what it does exactly, and how it is used practically in code.

Thanks for answering!

Comment: You can take the output from one command and pass it to the next command as input.

Comment: Besides the "pipeline" function already explained, the vertical bar is also used as bitwise OR operator in SET /A command, like this: `set /A "var=5 | 2"`

Comment: And to confuse even more there is the double pipe ||.  Which is used for conditional execution.  Execute the second command if the first command was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pipe [|]: Redirect standard output of commandA to standard input of commandB

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php

example :

```dos
echo KKZiomek | find "KKZ"
```

will redirect the `echo KKZiomek` in the input of the `FIND` and be used as second parameter of it.

Like well commented by **@aschipfl** the space is piped too.
so better use :

```
echo KKZiomek| find "KKZ"
```

Answer (score 6):

The pipe is used to [send the output of one command to the input of another command](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html).

For example, `del /p` will ask for confirmation when you delete files. However, you can pipe `echo y` to it to send a `y` to the del command and `del` will act as if the user had pressed `y`.