# how to write a batch script to open a program and start typing inside that program?

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I am new to batch, I do repetitive tasks at work and I wanted to automate some of it. How do I write a script to open a program **then start typing within that program** in specific input like my login credentials, then run commands inside that program.

The program I use is AIX UNIX to enter my login credentials then type in commands then create a log. Same program, same commands, same login info every time.

Like so far I have:

```
@echo off
start "" "C:\Program Files(86)\ProgramName"
echo myusername
```

The program opens but nothing gets typed into the program when I run it. Even though the program is waiting for me to type in my username.

Comment: You could try to pipe your data, but it only works if your other command accepts input fromm that way. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33292353/batch-what-is-the-pipe-used-for -- If you want cmd to send keys as If you entered it then CMD is not possible afaik. You would need autoit, autohotkey, PowerShell ... For that. Some apps cannot be forced to have a certan field activated, and it is always a way that might be tricky sometimes faulty. Try to find a more stabile solutions with the producer of the app.

Comment: First of all, you should learn some shell scripting for AIX, then find out how SSH-keys work (for password-less login), finally use PuTTY's companion program `plink.exe` to actually login and execute the script on the remote computer.